# RewriteRule .htaccess to catch multiple variables

Tags: .htaccess

I need to write a rule that take this url:

> localhost/restful/insert/1/kim/kim@gmail.com

to make this

> localhost/restful/index.php?function=insert&id=1&name=kim&email=kim@gmail.com

The .htaccess file will be inside the "localhost/restful/" folder.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Rewriterule ^restful/(\w+)/(\d+)/(\w+)/(.+)\@(.+) /restful/index.php?function=$1&id=$2&name=$3&email=$4@$5 [L]
```

Keep in mind that the RFC for email addresses does allow pretty much anything as address, so the only validation here is it having a @ in the middle.

This means you will end up with fake email addresses unless you add some other filter down the line.

Comment: There is a filter. Thank you so much. :)